# flex with bootstrap - stack issue when resizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I use flex as below and kinda new to flex world,

```
.couple-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

and other size in **`HTML`**, I use **`bootstrap grid system`** as shown below,

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 couple-container">
    <div class="col-sm-3 couple nikhilpic">
          div1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 couple-info">
        div2
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1 heart">
        div3 
        </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2 couple-info">
        div4
        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 couple vidyapic">
           div5
    </div>
</div>
```

**https://plnkr.co/edit/lGfsixyzoZnKX9qlY5VN?p=preview**

Above code gives me what I want in desktop view. eg. items are centrally aligned, contents are space-between.

**Problem:** when I shrink the size (tablet or mobile screen), I want, using flex, to get stack view(one above another) but unfortunately I don't get desire output.

This is what I want to achieve using mobile screen by just removing below lines,

**https://plnkr.co/edit/bcEbslGtOrTRH6AyGYsb?p=preview**

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
```

but look at the desktop screen everything is messed.

Comment: FYI your tag is misspelled. Should be bootstrap-grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is [`flex-wrap: nowrap`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property). This means that flex items are forced to stay in a single line. If you want flex items to wrap, you need to give the container `flex-wrap: wrap`.

However, when dealing with percentage lengths, a flex item may just shrink and not wrap. Or the wrapping may occur in an undesirable fashion. This seems to be the case in your layout.

Another option is to switch your layout from row-direction for desktop, to column-direction for mobile/tablet. Something like this:

```
@media ( max-width: 800px ) {
  .couple-container { flex-direction: column; align-items: stretch; }
}
```

[**revised plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/11SwRdE1RLFeJ3Jmq5sW?p=preview)